# MongoDB race condition on insert during load test

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

When performing load tests, I sometimes encounter a situation when this code (simplified):

```
var person = Persons.findOne();
if(person == null){
         Persons.insert(newDocument);
}
```

throws an error, because the insert operation conflicts with an existing document - even though I just checked that using findOne(). Mongo shell shows the document when pausing before the insert().

The error is:

```
WriteConcern detected an error ''. (Response was { "ok" : 1, "code" : 11000, "err" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: MainDB.Persons.$Person UniquePersonID dup key: { : \"BOT 878611 141152\" }", "n" : NumberLong(0) }).
```

The unique index is:

```
{ v: 1, name: "Person UniquePersonID", key: { UniquePersonID : 1 }, unique: true, ns: "MainDB.Persons", sparse: true, dropDups: true, background: true }
```

This smells like a race condition, and I'm trying to find the right way to resolve this:

1. using $setOnInsert
2. using findAndModify with Upsert flag
3. using Update with Replace and Upsert

The problem with those methods is that 1+2 only replace certain fields and I want to replace the entire document, and method 3 replaces an entire document but the _id is conflicted.

(If relevant, I'm using the official C# driver version 1.9.2.235)

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you be clear on exactly what error you receive and what you're ultimately trying to accomplish with that code? Document examples also help. It looks like you should just try to insert the document without a check, as if the document exists you'll get a unique key violation on _id, but it's hard to tell with the information you have given.

Comment: @wdberkeley - added more details, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if I am understanding correctly, you want to do the following:

1. Check if a document with a given UniquePersonId exists
2. If it doesn't, insert a document with that UniquePersonId
3. If such a document does exist, do nothing.

Your code hits the duplicate key error for the reason you think it does - another thread inserts the same UniquePersonId between the `findOne` and the `insert`. That's fine - the error just tells the code that some other process has done its work already. The unique index violation error isn't an error in the bad sense that something's not working right. It's just letting you know your operation is invalid because of the unique constraint that you imposed. I think (without knowing more about the context of this) that you can run the insert and just swallow the unique index error if it occurs.

Comment: So it can be something like: try{Insert();}catch{} to achieve that. But what you're saying is there's no better way to solve this?

Comment: What better way would you expect to exist? Seems perfectly fine to me.